# How to rename all subfolders with a specific Name

Tags: linux

How to go through all the subfolders and rename all the folders named 'Old' to 'New'

Answer (score 1):

If you have `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -QW '**/Old(/)' '**/New'
```

```
zmv -W '**/Old' '**/New'
```

Here `autoload zmv` loads `zmv` script that comes with zsh; `zmv -W pattern replacement` means «for each match remember value of all wildcards in `pattern` and replace corresponding wildcard characters in `replacement` with this value»; `zmv -Q` means «allow glob qualifiers in pattern»; `'**/Old'` means «match all files named «Old» in the tree under current directory» and `(/)` glob qualifier restricts «all files» to be only directories. Other useful `zmv` options:

- `-n`: do not do anything, just print what will be done.
- `-i`: show each line to be executed and ask whether to execute it
- `-f`: force overwriting of destination files

---

If you prefer [ba]sh:

```
RnAll() { for f in "$1"/* ; do [ -d "$f" ] || continue ; ( RnAll "$f" "$2" "$3" ) ; [ "`basename $f`" \== "$2" ] && mv "$f" "`dirname $f`/$3" ; done }
RnAll . Old New
```

This is almost pure sh (or at least bash) solution, that does not require anything but shell and coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
find . -type d -exec rename <rename options> \;
```

The rename options will vary depending on which `rename` you have. Red Hat rename uses `rename Old New {}`, whereas Debian/Ubuntu systems often use "Perl rename", which would use this syntax:

```
rename 's/^Old$/New/' {}
```

That will only change exact matches for "Old"; use `s/Old/New/g` if you want to change all occurrances of "Old" to "New", including multiple occurrances within one foldername.

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu systems often use "Perl rename", which would use this syntax: `rename 's/^Old$/New/' {}` ... that will only change exact matches for "Old"; use `s/Old/New/g` if you want to change all occurrances of "Old" to "New", including multiple occurrances within one foldername.